# bean with spring annotation in a jar, couldn't be scanned

Tags: spring, maven, jar, annotations

i get a problem. we declare some spring beans using annotation, etc:

```
@Controller
public class BookAction{}
```

it worked fine. but when we package it into a jar, the beans countn't be scanned, since we have set:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.nsm.framework" />
```

somebody said, in eclipse, we can export-->jar, and check "Add Directory Entiries", to solve this problem, it works

here are the differences:

jar with Directory Entries:

```
C:\>jar tf test_inside_with_de.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
net/
net/kyfxbl/
net/kyfxbl/test/
net/kyfxbl/test/inside/
net/kyfxbl/test/inside/action/
net/kyfxbl/test/inside/action/BookAction.class
net/kyfxbl/test/inside/action/BookAction.java
net/kyfxbl/test/inside/service/
net/kyfxbl/test/inside/service/IBookService.class
net/kyfxbl/test/inside/service/IBookService.java
net/kyfxbl/test/inside/service/impl/
net/kyfxbl/test/inside/service/impl/BookService.class
net/kyfxbl/test/inside/service/impl/BookService.java
spring-config.xml
struts.xml
```

jar without Directory Entries:

```
C:\>jar tf test_inside.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
net/kyfxbl/test/inside/action/BookAction.class
net/kyfxbl/test/inside/action/BookAction.java
net/kyfxbl/test/inside/service/IBookService.class
net/kyfxbl/test/inside/service/IBookService.java
net/kyfxbl/test/inside/service/impl/BookService.class
net/kyfxbl/test/inside/service/impl/BookService.java
spring-config.xml
struts.xml
```

but we are using maven, so my question is: how can i make a jar with Directory Entries in MAVEN3?

thanks a lot !

Comment: I don't understand; jars put class files in a package hierarchy, that's the only thing that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Your component-scan definition and the example classes do not seem to match.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="net.kyfxbl.test.inside*,com.xxx.nsm.framework" />
```

The * indicates that all sub-packages should be scanned as well.